# Binary Tree where data is different inherited type

Tags: c++, inheritance, tree, binary-tree

I have a base class with two classes inheriting from this, and a further two classes being inherited from these. I am required to use a binary tree in order to store data, however I do not quite understand how I would store the data in the tree. In examples I have seen, the data is simply an `int data` but mine could be up to four different types.

Comment: The question is a bit unspecific, generally you'd use a pointer or a smart ptr like `std::shared_ptr<Base>`. Do you have any code you could show or is this enough to get you started?

Comment: My base class is ``vehicle``,``car`` and ``motorcycle`` inherit the properties of it. I then have ``saloon`` and ``convertible`` inherit from ``car`` where ``moped`` and ``motorbike`` inherit from ``motorcycle``. 

In examples, a binary tree node is something similar to:

``node* left;
node* right;
int data;`` 

but I cannot do this as ``int data`` could be any of the 4 different inherited types.

Comment: I am unsure as to what the type for my data member should actually be as it could vary depending on the data being inserted.

Comment: Try using `std::shared_ptr<vehicle> data;` and research the proper use of shared pointers (e.g. create instances with `std::make_shared<saloon>(...)`, etc. If you get stuck, show the code you have (in a new question) and I'm sure someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

If all of your the types that you want to store in your tree are derived from the same base class, then your data member can be a pointer to that base class. This way, the pointer can point to an object of the base class or any of the derived types.

eg:

```
class Node
{
...
private:
    Vehicle* mData;
};
```

and then you can do something like:

```
node->SetData(new Car);
otherNode->SetData(new Moped);
```

or whatever interface you have for it, that sets the mData pointer to point to an object of some type in your class tree derived from Vehicle.